# Replace Id by UID in Laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel

Right now, all my routes are like this:

```
domain.com/clients/10/edit
```

I want to hide 10 that represents the client Id, and replace it with a generic UID, so that user doesn't access the id of the client ( He can know how many clients I have seeing the url ).

I saw a [library](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable/tree/master) that generate slugs. It has been very easy to implement. I just have to change references in my views, and specify in my model:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

according to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding)

Nevertheless, it is ok for resource that you can name, as a post, but for a categorySetting, I am not sure it is the right way to go.

Any idea how can I generate a "numeric slug"?

Answer (score 0):

Make a `generic_id` field in your clients table. Insert a unique generic id when new row is created:

```
$generic_id = range(1000, 20000);
shuffle($generic_id); // so it's unique

// or use uniqid()
```

Customize the key name in your Model:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'generic_id';
}
```